# Keycloak too many redirect

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I have 2 servers,

on the first server i run load balancer with nginx on docker compose

test.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  lb:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

and with nginx.conf

```
upstream backend {
    server server2:80 fail_timeout=3s;
    server server2:443 fail_timeout=3s;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  server1;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://backend;
        proxy_connect_timeout   2s;

        proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
    }
}
```

and on server 2, i run 2 instances of keycloak and postgre database with docker compose, i got the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/dasniko/059dc2a895f585f6f74edaa042a2da48) but i modify it to run on port 80 and 443 for testing.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passw0rd
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  keycloak1:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev -Djgroups.dns.query=keycloak
    environment:
      KC_CACHE: ispn
      KC_CACHE_STACK: kubernetes
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: passw0rd
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
      KC_SPI_EVENTS_LISTENER_JBOSS_LOGGING_SUCCESS_LEVEL: info
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
  
  keycloak2:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev -Djgroups.dns.query=keycloak
    environment:
      KC_CACHE: ispn
      KC_CACHE_STACK: kubernetes
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: passw0rd
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
      KC_SPI_EVENTS_LISTENER_JBOSS_LOGGING_SUCCESS_LEVEL: info
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    ports:
      - "443:8080"

volumes:
  pg-data:
    name: keycloak-demo-cluster-data
```

When i accessed it on the first server it works fine. but when i tried to access admin console or login it gave me this site can't be reached, too many redirects error. sometimes when the login success the dashboard game me error "network response was not ok.".

[image: Network response was not ok]

I'm trying to implement high availability for Keycloak using Docker.

i already tried to increase the fail_timeout but i doesnt works.
if i stop one of the Keycloak instance on server 2, it works fine. can you help me? thanks

Comment: config http://backend when assign server server2:443, it will trigger 307 Internal Redirect. is it cause the redirects error.